# How to find sampling frequency in aperiodic signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications, sampling, frequency, digital

I have a signal that is $x(t)=e^{-3/t^2}+2\cos(3\pi t^3)$ and I'm trying to find its proper value for fs. But I couldn't find a way on how to do it. I'm working on an interval $0<=t<=2$ and $x(t)$ in this interval is between $-2$ and $3$.

Comment: [LaTeX](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1722/50076)

Comment: Can you be more specific on what "proper value" means for the sample rate? $x(t)$ is a continuous signal that can be sampled at *any* sampling rate. What are you doing with the sampled signal?

Comment: I have to apply the sampled signal into the PCM system, quantize the signal and then determine an encoding scheme. My quantization range is [-2 3] if that helps.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the PCM signal afterwards? That's the point here: things like the sampling theorem specify minimum rates when you want to be able to do something specific, reconstruction of the harmonics-composed analog signal from the digital one. But your signal isn't reconstructible that way at all. So, that theorem doesn't apply. To know what you would need, we need to know what you would like to do with your PCM signal afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The signal is finite in time and hence it has unlimited bandwidth. You cannot sample it without aliasing. You can only derive a sample rate from the specific requirements of your application, i.e. how much aliasing can you tolerate ?

Comment: The only information I have is that the required minimum
mean squared quantization error is $10^-3$ but I don't think that's relevant to me determining a suitable Fs value.

Comment: It could be: if you assume, for example, a  white input spectrum, you can calculate the RMS error due to aliasing as a function of the sample rate. But really no idea whether that's what expected here. Is this a homework/class problem ?